# Change Meteor sort order with session?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have something like this:

```
var getArticles = function one() {

return articles.find({}, {sort: {'published': -1, 'votes': -1}, limit: 100});

};
```

And I want to change the sort order from 'published' to 'votes'.  I think you can do this with something like:

```
 Template.mytemplate.events({
 'click .sort_by_votes': function () {

Session.set('order', 'votes');
return getArticles();

 } 
});
```

but I'm not having any luck.  Anyone know how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Session.get` or `Session.equals` and make sure you dont split the helper functions and event functions

e.g

```
Template.mytemplate.events({
    'click .sort_by_votes': function () {
        Session.set('order', 'votes');
    }
});
```

then your template helper

```
Template.mytemplate.articles = function() {
    var sort = {published:-1, votes:-1};

    if(Session.equals("order", "votes")) sort["votes"] = 1

    articles.find({}, {sort: sort, limit: 100});
}
```

This is to hook up to your `mytemplate` template:

```
<template name="mytemplate">
    {{#each articles}}
         ...
    {{/each}}
</template>
```